# About counting measure on Borel sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be all finite unions of half open intervals, $\mathcal{A}=\sigma(\mathcal{C})$, i.e., the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Suppose that $\mu$ is the counting measure, and $\nu=2\mu$. Can anyone give me an example that $\mu(A)\leq\nu(A)$ fails to hold on $A\in\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: Never fails. However, we do have $\mu \ll \nu$ and $\nu \ll \mu$, maybe it is related to your situation.